# Difference between AWS::Serverless::Api and AWS::Serverless::HttpApi

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-sam, aws-http-api

I'm having a hard time understanding the difference between `AWS::Serverless::Api` and `AWS::Serverless::HttpApi`. I was looking at this AWS [repo](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model) for [Api](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#api) and [HttpApi](https://github.com/aws/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#httpapi) and wasn't able to understand why I'd use one over the other. I see there are different properties but still not sure of the difference between the two. I did check the AWS docs for [Api](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-api.html) and [HttpApi](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-httpapi.html).

Perhaps someone can elaborate on why you'd choose one over the other?

Comment: See [Choosing between HTTP APIs and REST APIs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html) and the original [HTTP API announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-http-apis-for-amazon-api-gateway/).